# Как вставить документ в mongodb используя строку в качестве _id

Tags: java, mongodb

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть коллекция в монге, где по историческим причинам `_id` является строкой.

При сохранении документа из Java

```
class MyDTO{
    String _id;
    String someData;
}

mongo.insertOne(myDTO);
```

в базу, вместо строкового `_id` вставляется `ObjectId`. Как можно запретить такое преобразование?

Использую драйвер `mongodb-driver-sync-3.10.2`

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Вам нужно переопределить вашу строку в [ObjectID](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/apidocs/index.html)

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId(yourID);
```